# Retrieve only last record of each entity and not all the records

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this MySQL query below.

```
SELECT doors.mac_addr,
       readers.reader_name,
       reader_records.value,
       reader_records.time_change
  FROM (building.readers readers
        INNER JOIN building.doors doors
           ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.id))
       INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
          ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.id)
 WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
ORDER BY reader_records.time_change DESC
```

It produces the following result;

```
(mac_addr, reader_name, value, time_change) VALUES
('B99A88', 'name_8', 1, '7/7/2016 7:21:48 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '6/21/2016 1:30:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 37.4, '5/4/2016 6:23:03 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 29.4, '5/4/2016 6:19:33 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 28.4, '5/4/2016 6:17:32 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 27.4, '5/4/2016 6:04:08 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 21.4, '5/4/2016 3:11:42 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 0, '4/20/2016 3:22:23 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '4/15/2016 5:39:52 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 0, '4/15/2016 5:39:46 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '4/11/2016 5:34:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '4/11/2016 5:33:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 0, '4/11/2016 5:33:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 28.4, '4/10/2016 9:20:20 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 32.5, '4/10/2016 9:00:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 34.2, '4/10/2016 11:29:00 AM')
```

However, it is not exactly what I want as it retrieves all records of each `reader_name`. What I want is to retrieve only the last record of each `reader_name`. The desired query I want should produce this output;

```
(mac_addr, reader_name, value, time_change) 
('B99A88', 'name_8', 1, '7/7/2016 7:21:48 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '6/21/2016 1:30:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 37.4, '5/4/2016 6:23:03 PM'),
```

How should my query be modified to get the desired result?

EDIT: What if last X records of each entity is required? Say, last 2 records. The desired result if last 2 records are required looks like this;

```
(mac_addr, reader_name, value, time_change) VALUES
('B99A88', 'name_8', 1, '7/7/2016 7:21:48 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 1, '6/21/2016 1:30:00 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__detect_1', 0, '4/20/2016 3:22:23 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 37.4, '5/4/2016 6:23:03 PM'), 
('B99A88', 'own__temperature_1', 29.4, '5/4/2016 6:19:33 PM')
```

Comment: It would be great if you share an **SQL FIDDLE** with the sample data

Comment: post your table structure..you could achieve result by group by time_change

Comment: How many times a day do we have to ask for it until we give up and just move on and never tell them

Comment: There are two same `reader_name` rows in your desired result.

Comment: @ 10086, corrected. THanks for catching the error.

Comment: So it is the typical variables question with an  `rn` and `grp`

Comment: Store dates/times using date/time data types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       IF(@rn = reader_name, @rowno := @rowno + 1, @rowno := 1) AS rowno,
       @rn := reader_name
FROM (
    SELECT doors.mac_addr,
           readers.reader_name,
           reader_records.value,
           reader_records.time_change
      FROM (building.readers readers
            INNER JOIN building.doors doors
               ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.id))
           INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
              ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.id)
     WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
    ORDER BY readers.reader_name, reader_records.time_change DESC
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := null, @rowno := 0) t2
HAVING rowno = 1
-- HAVING rowno <= 2
```

***Edited:***

```
SELECT mac_addr, reader_name, value, time_change
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
           IF(@rn = reader_name, @rowno := @rowno + 1, @rowno := 1) AS rowno,
           @rn := reader_name
    FROM (
        SELECT doors.mac_addr,
               readers.reader_name,
               reader_records.value,
               reader_records.time_change
          FROM (building.readers readers
                INNER JOIN building.doors doors
                   ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.id))
               INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
                  ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.id)
         WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
        ORDER BY readers.reader_name, reader_records.time_change DESC
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := null, @rowno := 0) t2
) t
WHERE rowno <= 2
```

Comment: What if last X records based on time_change are required instead of just the last row?

Comment: @LitAiy What kind of *based on time_change*? Show me your desired result.

Comment: I edited the question. `time_change` is one of the columns in the table which is a time-stamp of the record.

Comment: Then you can use `HAVING rowno <= 2`, check my answer again please. @LitAiy

Comment: You are brilliant. You make me feel stupid today:) Marked as CORRECT answer. If you don't mind, is it possible to remove `rowno` and `@rn = reader_name` from appearing in the output result?

Comment: Of course, wrap this query will do that, check it please. @LitAiy

Comment: I found an error in edited code. `WHERE rowno <= 2` should be inside bracket. Otherwise, it is perfect!

Comment: @LitAiy `rowno` is not a column in subquery, if you put it inside, you will get an error. You can try that.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the code. I'm still not good with SQL code. Would you mind having a brief explanation or are there any good links I can use to understand? May I ask why use CROSS-JOIN? I have never used it before.

Comment: I put `WHERE rowno <= 2` after CROSS-join. THere was no syntax error. The original code has `WHERE rowno <= 2` after the loop. I got syntax error.

Comment: Something is not right with the answer. Some rows returned are not the latest. When  rowno <= 3 or more, cannot return 3 rows. I will re-edit the question to include the schema.

Comment: @LitAiy Check it again. It's the `ORDER BY readers.reader_name, reader_records.time_change DESC`.

Comment: sorry, it's still the same.  Some rows returned are not the latest. When rowno <= 3 or more, cannot return 3 rows.

Comment: This is definitely right, I think there should be data problem in your table. @LitAiy

Comment: @10086 , I realized the problem. Your answer is perfectly correct for MySQL. I am using MariaDB and the query output is different. I created a new question for this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421218/query-for-top-n-per-group-code-works-for-mysql-but-difference-result-for-maria

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution if latest record per group is enough:

```
SELECT d.mac_addr,
       r.reader_name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(rr.value ORDER BY rr.time_change DESC), ',', 1) AS value
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(rr.time_change ORDER BY rr.time_change DESC), ',', 1) AS time_change
  FROM (building.readers r
        INNER JOIN building.doors d
                ON (r.gateway_id = d.id))
 INNER JOIN building.reader_records rr
         ON (rr.reader_id = r.id)
 WHERE (d.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
 GROUP BY d.mac_addr, r.reader_name
 ORDER BY d.mac_addr, r.reader_name;
```

With some tweaking it's also possible to achieve N latest rows, although the solution will be far from nice. See [this blog post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group).

Answer (score 3):

**STOP PRESS**: MySQL does not support windowing functions! So this won't work for you, sorry.

Try using a windowing function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

    `SELECT mac_addr, 
    reader_name, VALUE, time_change
    FROM (SELECT doors.mac_addr,
                 readers.reader_name,
                 reader_records.VALUE,
                 reader_records.time_change,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            ( PARTITION BY doors.mac_addr, readers.reader_name 
                              ORDER BY reader_records.time_change DESC ) rowno
            FROM (building.readers readers
                 INNER JOIN building.doors doors
                    ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.ID))
                 INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
                    ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.ID)
           WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88'))
    WHERE rowno = 1
    ORDER BY reader_records.time_change DESC`

Windowing functions are part of the ANSI standard so they tend to work the same across databases, my example was from Oracle. Once you've got the basics there are other useful windowing functions like `LEAD` and `LAG` which you could use to tell how long a door has been left open.

Answer (score 2):

If u r using SQL USE `TOP` 1 for getting the `TOP 1` row

```
SELECT TOP 1 doors.mac_addr,
           readers.reader_name,
           reader_records.value,
           reader_records.time_change
      FROM (building.readers readers
            INNER JOIN building.doors doors
               ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.id))
           INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
              ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.id)
     WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
    ORDER BY reader_records.time_change DESC
```

IN Mysql Use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT doors.mac_addr,
           readers.reader_name,
           reader_records.value,
           reader_records.time_change
      FROM (building.readers readers
            INNER JOIN building.doors doors
               ON (readers.gateway_id = doors.id))
           INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
              ON (reader_records.reader_id = readers.id)
     WHERE (doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88')
    ORDER BY reader_records.time_change DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes @Drew Edited the ans.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a subquery that returns the maximum (latest) time_change for each record_id:

```
select id, max(time_change) as latest_time_change
from reader_records
group by id
```

you can then insert the previous query in your original query:

```
select
  doors.mac_addr,
  readers.reader_name,
  reader_records.value,
  reader_records.time_change
from
  building.readers readers INNER JOIN building.doors doors
  ON readers.gateway_id = doors.id
  INNER JOIN (
    select id, max(time_change) as latest_time_change
    from reader_records
    group by id
  ) mr
  ON reader_records.reader_id=mr.reader_id
  INNER JOIN building.reader_records reader_records
  ON mr.reader_id = readers.id AND mr.latest_time_change=readers.time_change
 where
   doors.mac_addr = 'B99A88'
 order by
  reader_records.time_change DESC
```